# Why did a 10 minute video take up 32GB of space? (Canon 1200D)

Tags: video, sd-card

I have a Canon 1200D DSLR camera and last night I was recording a 20 minute live show but my 32GB card filled up in just under 10 minutes. I was shooting at 1920x1080 50FPS.

I had checked the manual before hand and it said I should have had 44 minutes on a 16GB card which equates to roughly 88 minutes on my 32GB card.
[image]

So why did this happen? Cheers!

Comment: First, the movie have 32Gb? One thing is too fill up a card, because on systems like OSX keeps recovery information on cards and it may fill up fast, even when it shows that the card is empty a 100Mb file may fill up the card. So that why I'm asking you... the file is 32Gb large?

Comment: did you format the card in camera before you started using it that day ? I have had issues like this from moving cards between cameras and not formatting them in the camera of use before using

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, that chart doesn't list 1920x1080 @ 50 fps, which is what you're shooting.  It lists 1920x1080 at 24, 25, and 30.  You can assume that you'll get around half the recording time listed when you double the frame rate.   But that should still get you around 44 minutes on an otherwise empty 32 GB card.  The fact that you didn't suggests that your card didn't have 32 GB of free space.  You probably had other pictures, movies, or files on the card already.  To get the full available recording time, you'll need to follow the manual's instructions on "formatting" the card.  Formatting a card erases all of its contents, so make sure you copy anything you want to keep over to a computer first.

Comment: My apologies, I actually meant 1280x720 at 50fps. I have edited the post, but nonetheless I have resolved the issue. The card was empty--or so I thought. Turns out there were hidden files reserved for different systems I had used the card for. I simply forgot to format the card before using it in this camera.